# Calculating totals by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

I'm new to SQL and have only been working with it for about 4 months. However I need to build a stored procedure that can calculate the total for like items (using numerical identifier ie. calculate total `E.ThisNumber Where E.ThatNumber = 'Whatever'`)

This is the code I have so far to retrieve the records I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo
WHERE DeptID = '010.4730'
AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-11-30 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY ProcedureID
```

Here's the output:

```
                           ProcedureID/
RowUpdateTime   Dept Code  E.ThatNumber  E.ThisNumber  E.WhatIneed

2013-11-30      010.4730    4200028      108.15       108.15
2013-11-30      010.4730    4200028       18.18       126.33
2013-11-30      010.4730    4200028       63.63       189.81
2013-11-30      010.4730    4200069        5.00         5.00
2013-11-30      010.4730    4200069        5.01        10.01
2013-11-30      010.4730    4200069        6.00        16.01
```

Notice how the count resets when the E.ThatNumber value is different than the previous entry. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

William Harley

Comment: what is your RDBMS? and do you need all the registries with the cumulative sum or just the total ?!

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studios

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: And what about the registries? just the total or do you want all of then with cumulative?

Comment: Jorge - Just totals by Corresponding ProductIDnumber. If there is a different product ID, then the total should reset. The ProductID being E.ThisNumber; The total needed for like E.ThisNumber fields WHERE E.ThatNumber is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you need, it might be this:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(ThisNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID)
FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo
WHERE DeptID = '010.4730'
AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-11-30 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY ProcedureID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I dont think the SUM operator can be used this way. Please see error message:                                                               Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: I really need a running total based on like field entries of a specific column in the same table. So for instacne if there are two products with the same product number, then add the total. However do not add totals for products with different product numbers.

Comment: 1) you need to cast your varchar column to numeric to sum it.  For example `SUM(CAST(ThisNumber as Numeric))` 2) I've no idea what you mean by product number, you did not include that in your original question -- is this a column you did not include that you want to sum for?  then change `PARTITION BY ProcedureID` to `PARTITION BY whatevercolumnyouwant`.

Comment: @user3199071 - Looking over the question -- did you mean ProductID where you put ProcedureID?  It seems so based on your comments.

Comment: I was giving a different example than what the original questions was just for clarity sake. I ended up using the original statement that you sent. Thanks so much. Really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 supports the cumulative sum as:

```
SELECT *,
       sum(thisnumber) over (partition by procedureId order by (select NULL)) as whatIneed
FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo
WHERE DeptID = '010.4730' AND
      SegmentDateTime = '2013-11-30 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY ProcedureID;
```

In earlier versions, you need to use a correlated subquery or join with aggregation.

By the way, there is no obvious ordering to the rows.  If you are doing a cumulative sum, you should really have a column that specifies the order.

Comment: Thank Gordon. I'm using SSMS 08. NOt sure how to do the Subquerying or Aggregation. Still a beginner. Thanks